# Using RenderPartial to assign Model Property values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am new to MVC platform and trying a simple application to get hold of the framework,

Application:I am designing an admin application which has a form to enter question and multiple options to the database, I have a viewmodel called "QuestionViewModel" which has properties "Quesiton" and a List of OptionsViewModel in it, "OptionViewModel" consists of "Option" and "IsRightAnswer" properties, so on the UI, I have a QuestionView which displays a textbox for Question and I want a question to have 4 options, so I created a PartialView called "QuestionOptionView" which takes "OptionViewModel" as its model,
now I loop about 4 times through the PartialView and display a TextBox for "Option" and "IsRightAsnwer" radiobutton,

The UI displays TetsBox for "Question" and 4 other "TextBoxes" for entering the "Options",
but when I Post this form, the "Options" does not bind to the ViewModel

How can I achieve Model Binding from these partialview data to the main viewmodel??

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Enter a question")]
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public IList<QuestionOptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
    public int MaxOptions { get { return 4; } }

    public QuestionViewModel()
    {
        Options = new List<QuestionOptionViewModel>();
    }
}

public class QuestionOptionViewModel
{
    public string Option { get; set; }
    public bool IsRightAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

> In the viewm I  have as below,

```
    @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("savequestion", new {}, FormMethod.Post)){

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Question)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Question)
    </div>

    <p>Add options for the question</p>

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.MaxOptions; i++)
    {
        { Html.RenderPartial("QuestionOption", new Babbi_Test_admin.Models.QuestionOptionViewModel()); }
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

When the form is submitted I have my post method as,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveQuestion(QuestionViewModel viewModel)
    {

    }
```

> My viewModel in the post has "Options" as null

Comment: it would be great if you show us your code

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee updated the question with code

Comment: Can you also add the code for the QuestionOption view

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee the QuesionOption just has a textbox for now as below,'code'@model Babbi_Test_admin.Models.QuestionOptionViewModel

<div>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Option)
</div>

Comment: Why are you calling the OptionViewModel in its constructor and not as a   variable?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee that is the root issue, I have no options yet, I need to create options from admin, so I enter a "Question", then "Enter Options" through renderpartial and then save those detials to DB

Comment: Yes, I understood but you need to pass the options as well from the View to Controller right, that is what is not being fetched right?

Comment: exactly @ArijitMukherjee

Comment: loop through MaxOptions and for each loop render html which has a textbox to enter the option, then submitting the form should post those options as well

Comment: That is what I'm trying to tell you Bro, that instead of calling the viewmodel in constructor call it as a variable

Comment: could you please drop in some code, I did not understand u properly

Answer (score 0):

This is happening cause you must be binding the QuestionViewModel with the Action of your Controller instead, you need to create a ViewModel that will have the `QuestionViewModel` `OptionViewModel`

**Error**

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveQuestion(QuestionViewModel viewModel)
{

}
```

In the Post Method you are expecting `QuestionViewModel` then how can you expect to get the `OptionviewModel`

Another thing your are Renbdering Partial View for `QuestionOptionViewModel` which Contains Options and RIght Answer so in the loop you will get the Right Answer 4 thing which is incorrect.

**Sample**

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
   //Properties
}
public class OptionViewModel
{
   //Properties
}

public class QuestionAndOptionViewmodel
{
  // QuestionViewModel and OptionViewModel model object
  //Constructors
  //Methods
}

[HttpPost]
public void SaveQuestion(QuestionAndOptionViewmodel viewModel)
{
    //Your Code Here;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.MaxOptions; i++)
    {
        { Html.RenderPartial("QuestionOption", Model.Options.Item(i)); }
    }
```

Or even better:

```
foreach(option in Model.Options)
{
   Html.RenderPartial("QuestionOption", option);
}
```

You will need to initialize the option values  in your Question Model constructor

Comment: but it will still not return the value in the post method